# Ensure writing has completed after `umount -l / --lazy`

Tags: unmounting

One of many issues with `umount -l` is that [there's way to know when it has completed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385645/how-do-i-know-when-sync-is-complete-after-a-umount-lazy).

Is there a way to:

- Know all writing processes have finished and all data has been written to disk.
- Prevent future writes

Answer (score 3):

Mount the filesystem's device again at a *new* location, say `/mnt`:

```
mount /dev/device /mnt
```

Then use:

```
mount -o remount,ro /mnt
```

This will attempt to remount the filesystem on the device read-only.

If this succeeds, there is no more data being written to the disk because [`mount -o remount,ro` is guaranteed to fail if there are files open for writing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385971/143394).

If the `remount,ro` fails, then use:

```
lsof +f -- /dev/<devicename> | awk 'NR==1 || $4~/[0-9]+[uw -]/'
```

to [list processes which are blocking the remount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101904/lsof-show-files-open-as-read-write#comment686090_115722).

If you are paranioid and want to prevent any future remount read-write, you can:

```
blockdev --setro /dev/device
```

---

Note: It seems that even mounting the device `ro` the first time may be sufficient. I get `mount: /tmp/mountpoint: /dev/loop0 already mounted or mount point busy.` if there are processes writing.